# Computing a best-fit quadratic approximation to a given function over a finite interval

Tags: multivariable-calculus, approximation, least-squares

I have a function of the form $$f(b) = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{N-b^2}-b+1) $$ on the interval $1\leq b < \sqrt{N/2}$. When I plot this curve for various values of $N$, I get a parabolic shape ($ax^2+bx+c$) whose coefficients I can determine by curve fitting using MATLAB for individual values of $N$. The approximate coefficients I get for this parabola are $$a\approx-\sqrt{0.1/N} , \qquad b\approx -0.47 , \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad c\approx \sqrt{N}/2 .$$ I would like to know if there is a proper way to arrive at these parameters or any other parabolic shape without resorting to empirical curve fitting? In other words, is there a way to express $f(b)$ as a parabola?

P.S: I tried the normal way of using $f(1)$ and $f(\sqrt{N/2})$ and deriving the coefficients $a$,$b$ and $c$, but the issue is that there is a large error term for large $N$. It would be nice to know any better method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure about the approximate coefficients $a, b, c$? The function $f$ is concave on that interval, but your approximating quadratic has $a > 0$ and so is convex.

Comment: Oops, sorry.. Forgot the minus signs.. Will fix it now!

Comment: Are you perhaps missing a factor of $2$ in your quadratic approximation? That would give close agreement with my answer (which graphical evidence suggests is a good approximation).

Comment: Indeed.. thanks for pointing it out. Sorry for the error.. am fixing it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which quadratic approximation $x \mapsto A x^2 + B x + C$ best fits the function $f(x)$ over the interval $[1, \sqrt{N / 2}]$ depends on your definition of "best", but a canonical choice is the quadratic whose difference from $f(x)$ has the minimal norm in $L^2([0, \sqrt{N / 2}])$. By definition the square of this norm is
$$M  := \int_1^{\sqrt{N / 2}} [f(x) - (A x^2 + B x + C)]^2 dx .$$
The integral is elementary, so this is straightforward (but tedious) to evaluate manually. The result, which is too long to typeset, is nonetheless simple in the way that matters for our purpose: It is a quadratic polynomial in $A, B, C$. (The dependence on $N$ is more complicated, but that's irrelevant to the next step.)

Our problem is now to find parameters $A, B, C$ that minimize this quantity $M$, but this is a standard exercise in multivariable calculus: We compute and classify the critical points---the  solutions $(A, B, C)$ to $\frac{\partial M}{\partial A} = \frac{\partial M}{\partial B} = \frac{\partial M}{\partial C} = 0$. Because $M$ is a nondegenerate quadratic in $A, B, C$, these conditions comprise a nondegenerate linear system in $A, B, C$, which means there is a unique solution, and this critical point turns out to be a minimum.

Linearity of the system also means that we can write this unique solution for $A, B, C$ as functions of $N$, but these are *really* complicated, and again typesetting them would be laborious (and the result not very illuminating). That said, we can produce good (and brief) asymptotic approximations for these quantities for large $N$. Expanding in series at $N = +\infty$ gives
$$
A = \frac{A_0}{\sqrt{N}} + O\left(\frac{1}{N}\right), \qquad
B = B_0 + O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\right), \qquad
C = C_0 \sqrt{N} + O(1) ,
$$
---and in particular retaining the leading term of each expansion gives a canonical quadratic approximation,
$$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{f(x) \approx \frac{A_0}{\sqrt{N}} x^2 + B_0 x + C_0 \sqrt{N}}} .$$
---where
$$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{
\begin{align}
A_0 &= - 120 + \frac{75}{2} \sqrt{2} + 15 \pi \sqrt{2}  = -0.32374\ldots \\
B_0 &= - \frac{83}{2} + 64 \sqrt{2} - \frac{63}{4} \pi = -0.47041\ldots \\
C_0 &= - 12 + \frac{33}{8} \sqrt{2} + \frac{3}{2} \pi \sqrt{2} = 0.49795\ldots
\end{align}
}}$$
These values agree closely with the manually estimated values given in the question.

Some graphical evidence shows that this is indeed a good approximation for large $N$ but is an underestimate for small $N$. One can improve the estimate, of course, by keeping more terms from the series approximation. For example, also retaining the constant term of the expansion for $C$, $\frac{299}{4} - \frac{225}{2} \sqrt{2} + 27 \pi \approx 0.47397\ldots$, dramatically improves the approximation for small $N$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I will try it out. But could you please tell me from where do you get $\frac{299}{2} - 225 \sqrt{2} + 54 \pi \approx 0.94795\ldots$ for $C_0$?. Or am I reading something wrong. I tried with the values of $A_0=-0.64749$, $B_0=-0.94083$ and $C_0=0.94795$, but I get woefully wayward values. Could you please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: I forgot to add in the previous comment.. I am trying for $N=100$.

Comment: I've adjusted the answer to account for the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ by which $f$ was modified in the original question. Does this resolve your issue?

Comment: Thank you. It does improve greatly, but still there is a significant difference. I think it has to do with low $C_0$ and $A_0$.. For example, with $N=1000000$ and $b=1$, the approximation gives $497.4793$ while the actual value is $499.9997$. Can more terms be added for $C_0$ and $A_0$ to solve the issue?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer one can recover $\sim 0.47$ of the difference by including the constant term of the series expansion of $C$, but a priori one shouldn't expect to be able to eliminate most of this gap by retaining more turns of the series---after all, the function $f$ isn't actually quadratic. One can impose the condition that the function and quadratic actually agree at $b = 1$ (which effectively eliminates one parameter) and search for the best fit among the functions that satisfy that condition, but necessarily doing so will result in a worse approximation elsewhere.

Comment: Indeed, computing the best-fit quadratic for $N = 10^6$ gives $|A| < 10^{-3}$, $B \approx -0.47$, $C \approx 498.43$, and so its value at $b = 1$ is $\approx 497.96$.

Comment: ...in fact, expanding again at $\infty$ the error of the best-fit approximation in the answer at $b = 1$ is $\left(\frac{25}{2} - \frac{33}{8} \sqrt{2} - \frac{3}{2} \pi \sqrt{2}\right) \sqrt{N} + O(1)$; the coefficient of $\sqrt{N}$ is $\sim 2 \cdot 10^{-3}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Travis. It helped me a lot. If it does not bother you too much, I would be grateful if you can give me the procedure that you used to arrive at the estimates of $A_0$,$B_0$ and $C_0$, if possible. It would help me to learn this. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful! It's no trouble, and the values I gave for $A_0, B_0, C_0$ are exact (and not "estimates" in any sense), in that they give precisely the leading terms in $N$ for the functions $A(N), B(N), C(N)$ that give the coefficients of the optimal quadratic approximation for any given $N$. To get $A_0, B_0, C_0$ we expand the functions $A(N), B(N), C(N)$ in series at infinity. (We can do this by expanding $A(u^{-1})$, etc. about $u = 0$.) I used a CAS to perform these manipulations---it would be routine (but very tedious) to do them by hand for this problem.

Comment: Hello Travis,
Since I am new to this area, I was wondering how do you arrive at these expressions: $A = \frac{A_0}{\sqrt{N}} + O\left(\frac{1}{N}\right), \qquad
B = B_0 + O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\right), \qquad
C = C_0 \sqrt{N} + O(1) $. Can you point me to some document that explains these ideas please?

Also, can a closed form expression be derived for $ \sum_{1}^{sqrt{N/2}}\lfloor{\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{N-b^2}-b+1)}\rfloor$?

Comment: These expressions are just big O notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation . To produce these expressions, we can just peel off the term that will dominate as $N \to \infty$; then we represent all the other terms by $O(X)$, where $X$ is a function that grows as fast (up to an overall constant) as the next-most-dominant term. The upshot is that for large $N$,e .g., $A$ will behave much like $A_0 / \sqrt{N}$.

Comment: Offhand I don't see any reason for there to be a nice expression for that sum, but you can probably find an asymptotic formula in $N$ and an error bound.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to share the algorithm you used to calculate this? I am not a mathematcian by trade, so it would be nice to learn so that I can tackle these kinds of fitting problems myself.

Comment: Sure: It's just writing our expression for $A$ as a linear combination of powers of $N$ and then keeping the highest-order term.

Comment: (If you're interesting in a worked example, it would probably be ideal to try it first with a less computationally messy problem than this one.)

Comment: Sure, I will try. In the meanwhile I have another problem.

[Counting-the-number-of-zeros-in-a-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137820/counting-the-number-of-zeros-in-a-series).

Could you please take a look and see if you can offer some suggestions?

Comment: I've written up (and answered) a question similar to this one, but where the function $f$ and the interval $[1, \sqrt{N / 2}]$ have been replaced by a function and interval that make the resulting expressions much shorter, which makes it much easier to be explicit about the computations that give the best approximation as well as the asymptotic expressions for its coefficients, e.g., the analogue of $\frac{A_0}{\sqrt{N}} + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Comment: Oh great! Could you please point me to the question? Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include the link. It's https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138638/how-to-find-the-best-quadratic-approximation-to-a-cubic-function-between-two-of. For future reference, you can find a list of questions that link to the question you're visiting on the right sidebar.